# VUEJS “Vue Hotel Datepicker” show calendar by default collapse open

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, datepicker, vue-component

We use https://github.com/krystalcampioni/vue-hotel-datepicker

By default the calendar is collapsed. On desktop resolution we want to show the calendar by default not collapsed but open.

exmaple:

[image]

Is this possible?

thanks ..renco

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is:

```
<HotelDatePicker alwaysVisible="true"/>
```